# C# Script version of PyBinding for WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, scripting, pybinding

I wrote a CSharpScriptBinding roughly equivalent to the PyBinding on CodePlex.  It uses the C# script engine from http://www.csscript.net.

After I wrote it, I kind of decided it might not really be something good to use.  Although it caches the compiled script code as an already compiled Assembly, my concern is that I will have one temporary Assembly created each time I use the binding.  Will this add up to a problem in the future?  If so, maybe there is a way in the C# script engine that I don't know about to optimize this further...?  Any thoughts to confirm my suspicion that this was just a bad idea (but useful excersise in learning more about bindings and converters)?

Answer (score 0):

Ask them if they use the DLR? Without it, I wouldn't trust it.